# Shifting LED from first LED

Tags: verilog

main.v

```
    `timescale 1ns / 1ps

module main(
    input reset,
    input clk, //50MHz
    output [6:0] led
    );
    reg [26:0] counter;
    reg trigger;
    reg [6:0] temp;
    initial begin
        temp <= 7'b0000001;
    end

    always @ (posedge clk, posedge reset) begin
        if (reset == 1'b1) begin
            temp <= 7'b0000001;
        end

        else begin
            counter <= counter + 1;
        end
    end

    always @ (counter) begin
        if (counter == 26'd50000000)begin //1Hz
            trigger <= ~trigger;
            counter <= 26'd0;
        end

    end

    always @ (trigger) begin
        temp <= (temp == 7'b1000000) ? 7'b0000001 :
                (temp == 7'b0000001) ? 7'b0000010 :
                (temp == 7'b0000010) ? 7'b0000100 :
                (temp == 7'b0000100) ? 7'b0001000 :
                (temp == 7'b0001000) ? 7'b0010000 :
                (temp == 7'b0010000) ? 7'b0100000 :
                (temp == 7'b0100000) ? 7'b1000000 : 7'b0000000;

    end
    assign led = temp; 
endmodule
```

The LED doesn't move. It stays on the first LED forever. Is it the trigger that didn't work or did I misunderstand the counter?

This is the working code. I don't know why I have to use if statement, but it works.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module main(
    input reset,
    input clk, //50MHz
    output [6:0] led
    );
    reg [26:0] counter;
    reg trigger;
    reg [6:0] temp;

    always @ (posedge clk, posedge reset) begin
        if (reset == 1'b1) begin
            counter <= 'b0;
            trigger <= 'b0;
        end
        else begin
           if (counter == 26'd50000000)begin //1Hz
              trigger <= ~trigger;
              counter <= 26'd0;
           end
           else begin
              counter <= counter + 1;
           end
        end
    end

    always @ (posedge trigger, posedge reset) begin
            if (reset == 1'b1) begin
                temp <= 7'd0;
            end
            else begin

            if (temp == 7'b1000000) begin
                temp = 7'b0000001;
            end

            else if (temp == 7'b0000001) begin
                temp = 7'b0000010;
            end

            else if (temp == 7'b0000010) begin
                temp = 7'b0000100;
            end

            else if (temp == 7'b0000100) begin
                temp = 7'b0001000;
            end

            else if (temp == 7'b0001000) begin
                temp = 7'b0010000;
            end                        

            else if (temp == 7'b0010000) begin
                temp = 7'b0100000;
            end

            else if (temp == 7'b0100000) begin
                temp = 7'b1000000;
            end                        

            else begin
                temp = 7'b0000001;
            end
            trigger <= 'b0;
            end
        end
    assign led = temp; 
endmodule
```

Comment: @NinjaCat as far as I am aware homework is allowed if they have had a good go at the question. The OP looks like they have tried to but with some misunderstandings of how the verilog language works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general structure for a a flip flop for an FPGA is to use an initial to set default values, or for ASIC use an async reset.

Looking at the code exert:

```
initial begin
    temp <= 7'b0000001;
end

always @ (posedge clk, posedge reset) begin
    if (reset == 1'b1) begin
        temp <= 7'b0000001;
    end

    else begin
        counter <= counter + 1;
    end
end
```

We have temp assigned a value in an async reset and an initial, while counter never get initialised. The more standard approach for creating a flip_flop with an async reset:

```
always @ (posedge clk, posedge reset) begin
    if (reset == 1'b1) begin
        counter <= 'b0;
    end
    else begin
        counter <= counter + 1;
    end
end
```

### Part 2

The next section of code is:

```
always @ (counter) begin
    if (counter == 26'd50000000)begin //1Hz
        trigger <= ~trigger;
        counter <= 26'd0;
    end
end
```

This has a manual sensitivity list which triggers on counter, It is best practise to use an automatic sensitivity list with `always @*`. This is also a combinatorial block so it should use blocking assignments (`=`).

In verilog a variable should not be assigned a value from multiple blocks, as counter is here. The exception is using initial blocks for default values.

Combinatorial blocks do not hold state, and this block only changes value on a particular count. implying trigger would hold its value, this will imply a latch. Accidentally implied latches can cause a lot of problems as is a bigger topic, than can be discussed here.

Consider doing this instead:

```
always @ (posedge clk, posedge reset) begin
    if (reset == 1'b1) begin
        counter <= 'b0;
        trigger <= 'b0;
    end
    else begin
       if (counter == 26'd50000000)begin //1Hz
          trigger <= ~trigger;
          counter <= 26'd0;
       end
       else begin
          counter <= counter + 1;
       end
    end
end
```

### Part 3

Your last section of code is again a manual sensitivity list:

```
 always @ (trigger) begin
```

This is not edge triggered so is a combinatorial section. A combinatorial loop is where the output is a function of itself. `temp = some function of temp`.

It looks like you really wanted to make this a flip-flop which updates on the positive edge of trigger:

**update**
I have also just noticed that you used a less than or equals, which will not work in this situation as you have the largest number first.

```
always @ (posedge trigger, posedge reset) begin
    if (reset == 1'b1) begin
        temp <= 'b0;
    end
    else begin
    temp <= (temp == 7'b1000000) ? 7'b0000001 : // <= changed to  ==
            (temp <= 7'b0000001) ? 7'b0000010 :
            (temp <= 7'b0000010) ? 7'b0000100 :
            (temp <= 7'b0000100) ? 7'b0001000 :
            (temp <= 7'b0001000) ? 7'b0010000 :
            (temp <= 7'b0010000) ? 7'b0100000 :
            (temp <= 7'b0100000) ? 7'b1000000 : 7'b0000000;
    end
end
```

Comment: I tried your code but it same as mine. It always stay on the first LED

Comment: Updated answer, and working example on [EDAplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/RiX)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use flipflops as async clock dividers you will need to use T-FF instead of D-FF. Using async generated clocks is no good style. The feedback to din is not needed any more.

Your FSM will never reach b00000100 because there is no transition. Please review your 'nextstage' encoding. This should be also the cause for the loop error.